# match parentheses in powershell using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to check for invalid filenames.  I want a filename to only contain lowercase, uppercase, numbers, spaces, periods, underscores, dashes and parentheses.  I've tried this regex:

```
$regex = [regex]"^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\._-\)\(]+)$"
$text = "hel()lo"

if($text -notmatch $regex)
{
    write-host 'not valid'
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: "parsing "^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\._-\)\(]+)$" - [x-y] range in reverse order"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to move the `-` to the end of the character class

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\._\)\(-]+)$
```

in the middle of a character class it needs to be escaped otherwise it defines a range

Answer (score 2):

You can replace a-zA-Z0-9 and _ with \w.

```
 $regex = [regex]"^([\w\s\.\-\(\)]+)$"
```

From get-help about_Regular_Expressions:

\w

Matches any word character.
Equivalent to the Unicode
character categories [\p{Ll}
\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}].
If ECMAScript-compliant behavior
is specified with the ECMAScript
option, \w is equivalent to
[a-zA-Z_0-9].

Comment: Also, you may not need the ^ or $ since those represent beginning of line/string or end of line/string

Answer (score 1):

I guess, add a backslash before the lone hyphen:

```
$regex = [regex]"^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\._\-\)\(]+)$"
```